# Is Twenty Eleven Theme Responsive ? any update?

Tags: responsive, theme-twenty-eleven

Someone asked me to make his site theme mobile friendly, and he gave me his theme which is Twenty Eleven theme. I want to know is this theme mobile friendly at all of has some bugs on mobile displays ?
Also is any recent updates to this theme, or will be in near future ? because I want to know if I want to make it responsive, should I make my changes as a child theme ? what’s the best way to change the source code of this theme ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this theme mobile friendly at all of has some bugs on mobile displays?

Go and preview the theme on your mobile device to find out if it's friendly or not - [wordpress.org/themes/twentyeleven](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyeleven/). You can also use a service like [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com) to test in various browsers and [testmysite.thinkwithgoogle.com](https://testmysite.thinkwithgoogle.com) to get a score for UX.

> Any recent updates to this theme, or will be in near future?

Trac show this theme was update in the last 3 months - Last updated: August 15, 2016 - [themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twentyeleven/](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twentyeleven/)

> If I want to make it responsive, should I make my changes as a child theme? what’s the best way to change the source code of this theme?

Read up on creating child themes - [codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)